# Rails 4: Has anyone encountered jquery_ujs mangling callback url, which breaks ajax screen update?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Catch-22 -- if I load jquery_ujs in my app, at execution time I observe jquery_ujs code pull the wrong path/url value out of rails, which spawns a quiet (e) when it requests the non-existent url from the server.

If I don't load jquery_ujs in application.js, the callback url is not mangled, and the page updates as expected, but I then I forfeit rails.js. Boo.

New to rails. I don't know enough to know if the answer is staring me in the face. Maybe it is. Do I have gem collision problem, maybe? Ideas? Suggestions?

May be relevant: Using Google maps api. Active listeners on map-canvas.

### application.js (w/o jquery_ujs)

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

(rails.js is *not* in the tree )

### Gemfile

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby                          '1.9.3'
gem 'bcrypt',                 '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                  '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',            '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',            '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                    '~> 1.23.0', require: 'fog/aws/storage'
gem 'rails',                  '4.1.4'
gem 'pg'
platforms :mswin do
  # gems specific to windows
  gem 'tzinfo'
end
gem 'geocoder',               '1.2.6'
gem 'validate_url'
gem 'country_select',         '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate',          '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate','0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',         '3.3.1'
gem 'simple_form',            '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder',               '~> 2.0'
gem 'rails-html-sanitizer',   '1.0.1'
gem 'sdoc',                   '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

group :development do
  gem 'spring'
end

group :assets do
# NTS sprockets-rails claims to include this  gem 'sass-rails'
# NTS sprockets-rails claims to include this  gem 'coffee-rails',            '~> 4.0.1'
  gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 2.2.0', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
  gem 'uglifier',                '>= 1.3.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor',     '0.0.2'
  gem 'unicorn',            '4.8.3'
end
```

Comment: I don't really get what the problem is but it is very unlike that the problem is jquery_ujs. I wold try 2 things: first ugrade Rails to 4.2 and see if the problem persists and if this doesn't fix it I would remove turbolinks and try without it. This is just for testing purposes and is it just guessing, it is strange what happens. Maybe you should take a closer look at your code

Comment: I would definitely not rule out my code... I'll try both of your test suggestions and post results. Trying Rails 4.2 is a good idea. Thanks, Octopus-Paul.

Comment: Thanks, @Octopus-Paul I tried both and it did turn out to be turbolinks mangling the callback. I did find a fix which seems to allow me to keep turbolinks and jquery_ujs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried skinny version of app without Google Map API DOM listeners loaded and without Turbolinks. Ajax works. Put Google Map API back in and ajax still works. Turbolinks added back in and ajax broken.

I got Turbolinks back and the DOM listener callback working by doing the following:

1. Updated rails to 4.2.0 (needed to do this anyway)
2. Added jquery_rails and its runtime dependencies to gemfile

   gem 'jquery-rails',            '~> 4.0.3'

   gem 'rails-dom-testing', '~> 1.0.5'

   gem 'railties', '~> 4.2.0'

   gem 'thor', '~> 0.19.1'

   gem 'nokogiri'

   gem 'activesupport', '~> 4.2.0'
3. Application.js

   //= require jquery

   //= require jquery.turbolinks

   //= require jquery_ujs

   //= require bootstrap

   //= require turbolinks

   //= require_tree .
4. Javascript hooks

destroy.js

```
// Ajax handlers, destroy a following relationship
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('/users/follow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

create.js

```
// Ajax handler, create a following relationship
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('/users/unfollow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

Turbolinks is something you need to make an informed decision about using. It has benefits and drawbacks. There are real issues, but I'm staying with it, for now.

---

**ADDED**
Posting another Q&A which sheds more light into this niggling problem:  [Rails 4: Has anyone encountered jquery_ujs mangling callback url, which breaks ajax screen update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990590/rails-4-has-anyone-encountered-jquery-ujs-mangling-callback-url-which-breaks-a)

Comment: Here is relatedinformation: jQuery plugin for drop-in fix binded events problem caused by Turbolinks https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Comment: In case someone come across this thread looking for information, here's the git resource with Turbolinks  open issues https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues. Turbolinks can create hard to debug problems, but you have to weigh the advantages it provides against the problems it may introduce and make a decision.